# Where is the /var/www/ located on the ftp of an ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Well, its a fresh new ubuntu server, and wordpress is running on it. I just cant access the files cuz i dont know where thy are.

I've tried changing permissions on var but that worked, but there is no /www.

```
There is no code
```

On the FTP is shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for folders on Ubuntu 18.04 with:

```
find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "www"
```

Comment: on filezilla.. i need that on filezilla lol

EDIT: i did the cmd on ssh and it didnt come back with anything? is that good?

Comment: "That means there is no "/www" on your system. I wonder if Wordpress is installed correctly." You did do it in the terminal right?

Comment: Yeah. Add me on discord so we can talk more. Noobinator#5742

Comment: and i can screenshare

Answer (score 0):

How to Install and configure [Apache](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-apache#0) for Ubuntu

How to check running status of Apache HTTP web server:

```
$ service apache2 status
```